# Spring - inner methods called by @Transactional(readOnly = true) method to write

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

If a method has annotation @Transactional(readOnly = true), is there a way to allow inner methods to write?

Example:

```
Class A {
   @Transactional(readOnly = true) 
   public void readFoo(){
       b.writeFoo();
   }
}

Class B {
   public void writeFoo(){}
}
```

I know it sort of defeats the purpose of having the readOnly annotation but I just want to know if there's a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` worked for me. A thing to be cautious about is that if the method takes in a hibernated object, this will not work. This only works if you retrieve the hibernated object and makes changes within the Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW method.

Answer (score 0):

`readOnly` attribute of `@Transaction` annotation is just hint for the transaction manager. It depends on underlying technology you use to manage transactions. It can just optimize transactions read-only performance (Hibernate) or it can simply ignore `readOnly` attribute at all.

I think that if you annotate `writeFoo()` i.e. like this

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
```

It can act independently on parent read-only transaction and write without problems. But I haven't tested this myself.